# URL Rewriting dont work with variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, wamp

This is a rule in htaccess file :

```
RewriteRule ^Serie-examens-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)$ examens-list.php?idChapitre=$1&idTitre=$2 [L]
```

In href i've put this url :

```
href="<?php echo 'Serie-examens-'.$idChapitre.'-'.$idTitres[0].'-debuter');?>"
```

i've this error when i click in the link :

```
Not Found

The requested URL /SerieJava/Serie-examens-1-1-debuter was not found on this server.
```

I'm using wamp, and i test rewriting url without variables , it works

where is the error in the rule ?

The Full .htaccess file :

```
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /SerieJava/

RewriteRule ^Le-premier-chapitre chapitre1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^Serie-examens-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)$ examenss-list.php?idChapitre=$1&idTitre=$2 [L]
```

thanks

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: In this directory : wamp/www/SerieJava/.htaccess

Comment: Have you switched on the rewrite engine?

Comment: Can you show your full `/SerieJava/.htaccess`

Comment: There's a syntax error in your PHP

Comment: Yes with RewriteEngine On

Comment: my htaccess : 

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^Le-premier-chapitre chapitre1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^Serie-examens-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)$ examens-list.php?idChapitre=$1&idTitre=$2 [L]

Comment: i delete the ')' in href, it's same

Comment: By the way... Why do you have the () around [a-zA-Z]+ for debuter (which would be $3)? If you are not using it anywhere.

Comment: Posting your `examens-list.php` file content would help.

Comment: @tastro : how i post it ? it's very big file, and it works well

Comment: Then post just the part which has to do with retrieving `idTitre` (`$_GET['idTitre']`) and processing it. I saw that you have an array or something for `$idTitres[$2]`. Maybe that this is not coded well and that why your file returns a 404.

Comment: Save your current `examens-list.php` file and then replace it with another one which will have only this text in it: "It works!" or something like that... Just to see if the PHP is returning the 404 or the http server.

Comment: @tastro : my $idTitre is static varibale declared in file like this : $idTitres = array(1,2,3);

Comment: @tastro : i replace it, and i've the same error.

The body of examens-list.php : 

<body>
<?php 
echo 'it works';
?>

Comment: @user3817737 ok... So it's not PHP who's causing the problem. No need for your PHP then. ;)

Comment: @user3817737 try UPDATE #3 in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a closing ) in the link php that should not be there:

```
href="<?php echo 'Serie-examens-'.$idChapitre.'-'.$idTitres[0].'-debuter');?>"
                                                                         ^ here
```

That probably leads to a php error that invalidates your link.

**Edit:** Also note that you are using this to rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^Serie-examens-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)$ examens-list.php?idChapitre=$1&idTitre=$2 [L]
```

The `^` denotes the start so if your path is `/SerieJava/Serie-examen....` it will not be rewritten because it starts with `/SerieJava/`.

You should post the whole `.htaccess` file to see if that is the problem but it looks like it is.

Comment: @user3817737 What does the html source look like?

Comment: <a href="<?php echo 'Serie-examens-'.$idChapitre.'-'.$idTitres[0].'-debuter';?>" id="titre1">Debuter</a>

Comment: @user3817737 If that is the html source, then the php is not being processed but I doubt that based on your question. Can you post the real html source from the browser?

Comment: here is my .htaccess : 

SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^Le-premier-chapitre chapitre1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/SerieJava/Serie-examens-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)$ examens-list.php?idChapitre=$1&idTitre=$2 [L]

Comment: @user3817737 Get rid of the starting forward slash: `RewriteRule ^SerieJava/Serie-exa...`. You might need a forward slash or complete path for `examens-list.php` though...

Comment: the html source from browser : 

'<a href="Serie-examens-1-1-debuter" id="titre1">Debuter</a>'

Answer (score 0):

This should be your `/SerieJava/.htaccess`:

```
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0

<Files .htaccess>
   order allow,deny
   deny from all
</Files>

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /SerieJava/

RewriteRule ^Le-premier-chapitre chapitre1.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^Serie-examens-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+) examens-list.php?idChapitre=$1&idTitre=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: What happens when you enter `http://localhost/SerieJava/examens-list.php?idChapitre=1&idTitre=$1` in your browser?

Comment: initialy the page is called with these link, it work's normaly, and now when i try to add the rewriting url i've the bug

Comment: When you visit `http://localhost/SerieJava/examens-list.php?idChapitre=1&idTitre=1` in your browser doe it open correct page for you?

Comment: Verify whether your `/SerieJava/.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: it's enabled, i've 500 internal server when i add same garbage in it

Comment: Edit your question provide your latest & full `/SerieJava/.htaccess`

Comment: Hmm my last rule looks different from your .htaccess in question

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `/` to your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /SerieJava
RewriteRule ^/Serie-examens-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)$ examens-list.php?idChapitre=$1&idTitre=$2 [L]
```

Notice the `/` after the `^` and before `Serie`

You may also try removing the carot from the rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /SerieJava/
RewriteRule Serie-examens-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)$ examens-list.php?idChapitre=$1&idTitre=$2 [L]
```